# Можно ли задать одно название функции с разным количеством параметров?

Tags: pyqt5

```
def Line(self, A):
    print (A)

def Line(self, A, B):
    print (A, B)

def Line(self, A, B, C):
    print (A, B, C)

def Line(self, A, B, C, D):
    print (A, B, C, D)
```

Данный код не работает,
можно ли сделать чтобы "Line" автоматически определяла то количество параметров, которое я передам в нее ?

Comment: [Python function overloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434482)

Comment: а можно разъяснить?, не оч понятно....

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class overload:
    def __init__(self, f):
        self.cases = {}

    def args(self, *args):
        def store_function(f):
            self.cases[tuple(args)] = f
            return self
        return store_function

    def __call__(self, *args):
        function = self.cases[tuple(type(arg) for arg in args)]
        return function(*args)


@overload
def f():
    pass

@f.args(int, int)
def f(x, y):
    print('two integers')

@f.args(float)
def f(x):
    print('one float')


f(1, 2)
f(1.462)
```

работает...